# Libgdx Exported Jar - Can't find main class - LD25

Tags: java, export, libgdx

I'm doing the Ludum Dare 25, using Java Libgdx trying to export my jar.

It  was working absolutely fine earlier, I exported and could run it fine. Now when I export it the exact same way, it crashes as soon as I open it. Running via CMD I get the error

'Could not find or load main class'

I've opened it up in winrar and checked the Main class is there and the manifest points to the correct place. I don't understand what's wrong.

All help appreciated, many thanks!

**Solution Found**
Odd issue, despite the error message had nothing to do with the class, the jar exporter made one of my image files lowercase or something, so that it was messing up it's references

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace or exception you're seeing?  Can you see if the superclass (or other classes referenced by your main class) are also where you expect them in the .jar?

Comment: Have you added all other external Jars to the buildpath? Eclipse or Netbeans?